# jQuery / Dynatree: How to populate dynatree dynamically using asynchronous ajax call?

Tags: jquery, treeview, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

Hi I'm new to dynatree, but I find it very cool.

I am trying to use this treeview in my app where I need to populate the tree based on dropdown slection event in my page. 
The tree will be initially and will only needs to be populated based on the selections in dropdown fields in the page.

I tried to read the documentation, but couldnt figure out how to do this or if the tree even supports asynchronous ajax calls for data.

Can someoone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example: http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-init-lazy.html and click [View source code]